# How to unwrap an optional dictionary value in Swift 4+ in one step?

Tags: swift, dictionary, unwrap

Given the dictionary of dictionary below, what is the correct syntax to unwrap the Int? in one step?

```
let dict:Dictionary<String, Dictionary<String, Int?>> = [
"parentKey" : [
    "firstKey" : 1,
    "secondKey" : nil]
]

let x = "someKey"
let y = "someOtherKey"
var foo = 0

if let goo = dict[x]?[y] { foo = goo } //<-- Error: cannot assign (Int?) to Int

if let goo = dict[x]?[y], let boo = goo { foo = boo } //<-- OK
```

In the first 'if let', goo is returned as an Int? - goo then needs to be unwrapped as in the second 'if let'...

What is the correct syntax for doing this in one step?

Comment: `if let goo = dict[x]?[y] ?? NSNotFound { foo = goo }` ?

Comment: This gives the correct result when both keys are valid (e.g. x = "parentKey, y = "firstKey" or y = "secondKey". However, it gives an incorrect result when either x or y is a non-existent key (e.g. x = "someKey" or y = "someOtherKey")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understood you want to force unwrap a double optional. There different methods.

```
let dbOpt = dict[x]?[y]
```

My favorite:

```
if let goo = dbOpt ?? nil { foo = goo }
```

Using `flatMap`:

```
if let goo = dbOpt.flatMap{$0} { foo = goo }
```

Using pattern matching:

```
if case let goo?? = dbOpt { foo = goo }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use nil colesecing and provide a default value. Only way to safely unwrap a dictionary value.

```
if let goo = dict[x]?[y] ?? NSNotFound { foo = goo }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this but one of the simplest solution available is :

```
var foo = 0

if let goo = dict[x]?[y]  as? Int{
    foo = goo
}
print(foo)
```